# Using Flask-SQLAlchemy, what shoud I do each time an upgrade fails after a migration script has been successfully generated?

Tags: python, sqlite, database-migration, flask-sqlalchemy

The Flask-SQLAlchemy *db migrate* command works fine most of the time. However after that, running *db upgrade* sometimes returns errors: for instance, trying to ALTER an SQlite column from NULL to NOT NULL.

When this happens, I just get stuck; because I cannot undo the migration, *db downgrade* doesn't solve the problem either. Most times I have to loose all data in the DB and then look for other ways to recover some of them.

What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to run:

```
db stamp head
```

in case upgrade fails.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When should I do this?